# CreateProcess() function cannot run. Error The memory could not be written

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, console-application, createprocess

I'm using Windows 8 x64 Enterprise, VS2010.

I've some problem on `CreateProcess()`.

I've created a Win32 Console project to execute `_backround_manipulator.exe`, my application.

Implementation here.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD RunManipulator(TCHAR* tszProcessPath);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _tprintf(_T("---Manipulator will start...---\n"));
    if(0x08 == RunManipulator(_T("_background_manipulator.exe")))
        _tprintf(_T("---Manipulator Started.---\n"));
    else
        _tprintf(_T("---Manipulator cannot run.---\n"));
    return 0;
}

DWORD RunManipulator(TCHAR* tszProcessPath)
{
    STARTUPINFO _v_startupinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION _v_processinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&_v_startupinfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&_v_processinfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    _v_startupinfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, tszProcessPath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &_v_startupinfo, &_v_processinfo));
    {
        return 0x12;
    }

    return 0x08;
}
```

But cannot pass `CreateProcess(NULL, tszProcesPath, /*...*/)` function on `debug` mode.

**Error** like this;

[image]

What's wrong on my code? 
Is it because I created the Console Project?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger step-by-step and find which line causes the error?

Comment: I cannot pass on CreateProcess function.

Comment: 1) You have semicolon after `if`, which I guess is not the desired behavior.

2) Adding `GetLastError` in the case of failure reports `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Do you have `_background_manipulator.exe` in the path?

Comment: Thank you, @karastojko. Read carefully my problem. 1) Have you set same evironment as me? I mean `ConsoleProject`. 2) Also same error will occur after change `_background_manipulator.exe` into `calc.exe`.

Comment: your `tszProcesPath` is read only. what here unclear ? trivial error

Comment: @RbMm, thank you. I cannot find why `tszProcessPath` is read only. Do you know why this happens? I did not do anything to `tszProcessPath`.

Comment: @A.Godnov: Thanks for the point - usually I read the question and try the given code. It works when `calc.exe` is used (in the Console mode).

Comment: the string literals like "_background_manipulator.exe" usual is in read only section placed .rdata

Comment: Is the Readonly, Writeonly attributes related to CreateProcess? It looks like the Writeonly attribute does not matter. Do I just have to read and write? Please tell me more.

Comment: @karastojko, I'm really glad that you are running code well. But I really don't know why that error occurs. I am looking for a cause because I can't execute specified process. I think something is coming up now, from Mr. RbMm.

Comment: Why use TCHAR? Do you really support Windows 95?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if look for definition of [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_    LPCTSTR               lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_ LPTSTR                lpCommandLine,
  ...
```

we can note that *lpCommandLine* defined as In-**out** parameter and defined not as const pointer ( compare with *lpApplicationName* which is const pointer LP**C**TSTR)

and :

> The Unicode version of this function, **CreateProcessW**, can modify
>   the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a
>   pointer to read-only memory (such as a **const** variable or a
>   **literal** string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

but you exactly pass **literal string** `_T("_background_manipulator.exe")` as *lpCommandLine*. and got excepted result - memory could not be written

Comment: Thank you. I just solved the problem using another `TCHAR` variable. Point ; `_tcscpy(tszCommandLine, tszProcessPath);` Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @RbMm this is a dupe hundreds of time over, perhaps better close as such